# How can I find similarities in two graphs?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, similarity, graphs, numpy

Let's say that I have two 1 dimensional arrays, and when I plot the two arrays they look like this:

[image]

If you look at the top and bottom graphs, then you can see that the highlighted parts are very similar (in this case they're exactly the same). I need to find a way to find these sections using some sort of algorithm or method.

I've tried searching everywhere in the numpy and scikit docs, I even searched everywhere on stackexchange and couldn't find a solution for this problem. I don't think anyone published a solution for this yet.

Does anyone have any idea how I can find similar sections in two graphs? My dataset is a 1 dimensional data array for each graph, and I need a algorithm that tells me where the similar parts are. Just remember that the similar sections are never 100% the same, sometimes they're a little bit off and sometimes there's anomalies so a small part would be different but everything else will still look the same. Also you can ignore the curvature of the graph, that's irrelevant. Only the X and Y coordinates of the data points are important.

I can't read explanations that have a lot of maths inside of them and I also can't turn explanations that have a lot of maths into code, I'm still learning how to do that at University. But I'm really good at reading pseudo-code and other programming languages so please give me an answer with real code.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to first define what your threshold for 'similar' is, and also what length of similarity is meaningful to you.

One way of achieving this is by taking a 'slice' of the first set of coordinates, and comparing them against each slice of the same size in the second set. If all values are within a certain threshold distance, bingo.

You can then repeat this with the next slice of coordinates from set #1.

e.g. here is an O(n<sup>2</sup>) implementation:

```
slice_len = 10
thresh = 2
overlap_x1 = []
overlap_x2 = []

for i in range(len(x1)-slice_len):
    for j in range(len(x2)-slice_len):
        # checking the y coords are all at most 'threshold' far away
        if max(abs(y1[i:i+slice_len]-y2[j:j+slice_len])) < thresh:
            # Adding the similar x-coords to the containers
            overlap_x1.append(x1[i:i+slice_len])
            overlap_x2.append(x2[i:i+slice_len])

# Converting arrays to ordered sets to remove duplicates from overlap
# Since they are x-coords, they are monotonic increasing, order is preserved
overlap_x1 = OrderedSet(overlap_x1)
overlap_x2 = OrderedSet(overlap_x2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in simply O(1) complexity using Deep learning technique called *oneshot learning*. If you are to find the exact match, we are going to set the cosine similarity to 1 and convolve the kernel over the second image and calculate the difference with the first image to find the difference. Read further about one_shot learning [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rsalakhu/papers/oneshot1.pdf).

Comment: I don't quiet understand how oneshot can be used here. Isn't oneshot used for categorizing images? That's what understood from that research paper and other articles online.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the functionality of the same can be extended for your case too. In your case, the plot images should be absolutely same and so a concept like sliding window can be coupled with one-shot learning and used to find same graphs (Visually same).